# Eclipse maven plugin: Cannot run program "mvn" for WSO2 ESB SampleServices

Tags: wso2, maven-3, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

All are good if I used `mvn clean install` via command line inside *SampleServices* of the [pre-packaged project](https://github.com/wso2-docs/WSO2_EI/blob/master/Integration-Tutorial-Artifacts/StoreAndForwardTutorial.zip). But it gives me this error when I try to `mvn clean install` it via eclipse m2e

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec
>   (package) on project SampleServices: Command execution failed. Cannot
>   run program "mvn" (in directory
>   "/Users/johndoe/Project/ChickenEngine/SampleServices/target/capp"):
>   error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

I've tried using external maven located at `/opt` but still no success. I'm following [this guide.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Deploying+Composite+Applications+in+the+Server)

Comment: maven suppose to be executed in dir where pom.xml is located. Your  message says Cannot run program "mvn" in ....../target/capp . Target directory is created by maven and located in basedir/target. And basedir is directory where pom.xml suppose to be located

Comment: the maven configuration base workspace in eclipse is where the pom.xml is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually find out to pay more attention to problem

SampleServices\pom.xml configure exec-maven-plugin. Important part is maven itself is called as executable

```
<executable>mvn</executable>
    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
    <arguments>....
```

This means that mvn.bat has to be in PATH. Use variable PATH or run eclipse from cmd, but before start of application execute

```
 set PATH=%PATH%;c:\path-to-maven-bin-directory\
```

and only then

```
./eclipse.exe
```

and u will get in eclipse console

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] QueryDoctorEP ...................................... SUCCESS [  2.855 s]
    [INFO] GrandOakEP ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.057 s]
    [INFO] ClemencyEP ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.064 s]
    [INFO] PineValleyEP ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.067 s]
    [INFO] ChannelingFeeEP .................................... SUCCESS [  0.044 s]
    [INFO] SettlePaymentEP .................................... SUCCESS [  0.051 s]
    [INFO] HealthcareAPI ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.776 s]
    [INFO] PaymentRequestMessageStore ......................... SUCCESS [  0.599 s]
    [INFO] PaymentRequestProcessingSequence ................... SUCCESS [  0.541 s]
    [INFO] PaymentRequestProcessor ............................ SUCCESS [  0.597 s]
    [INFO] SampleServices_module .............................. SUCCESS [  0.437 s]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 7.829 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-23T12:23:58+03:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/209M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 23.775 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-23T12:23:58+03:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/201M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```